# Checkbox column in Infragistics win ultragrid

Tags: winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Am a newbie to Infragistics.
On my winforms app, am using Ultrawingrid to display data from database.

How do I show a checkbox column as the first column in the grid?
Also, I need to capture check/uncheck event and then read the corresponding grid row/cells in the application.

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please post the code of the InitializeComponent() method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

You need to get a hold of the UltraGridColumn instance for the column you want rendered as a checkbox.  Something like:

```
UltraGridColumn ugc = myGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[@"myColumnKey"];
```

Then change the column's display style to checkbox and make sure it allows edits:

```
ugc.Style = ColumnStyle.CheckBox;
ugc.CellActivation = Activation.AllowEdit;
```

In my opinion, it's appropriate to have this grid initialization code in a handler for the form's Load event or the grid's InitializeLayout event.

Handle the grid's CellChange event to see when the user changes the checkbox value:

```
private void mygrid_CellChange(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
{
    if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(e.Cell.Column.Key, @"myColumnKey"))
    {
         // do something special when the checkbox value is changed
    }
}
```

As requested, here is sample code that demonstrates adding an unbound column, moving it to the leftmost position, handling the cell change event, and retrieving an additional value from the grid.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Trusted_Connection=true"))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from sysobjects", conn);
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(ds); 
            ultraGrid1.DataSource = ds;
        }
    }

    private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        UltraGridColumn checkColumn = e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Add(@"checkColumnKey", @"caption");
        checkColumn.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.CheckBox;
        checkColumn.CellActivation = Activation.AllowEdit;
        checkColumn.Header.VisiblePosition = 0;
    }

    private void ultraGrid1_CellChange(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(e.Cell.Column.Key, @"checkColumnKey"))
        {
            return;
        }

        bool checkedState = bool.Parse(e.Cell.Text);

        DataRowView row = e.Cell.Row.ListObject as DataRowView;
        string name = row.Row[@"name"] as string;

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Checked={0}, name={1}", checkedState, e.Cell.Row.ListObject));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton PaulF, but I need to add this checkbox column as an unbound one.And I need to show it as the first column in the grid ahead of the all the db columns.Now it is showing up as the last column.Also, when I click on the checkbox, it is not getting checked even after setting CellActivation to AllowEdit.Please help.

Comment: Hi Jimmy . Thanks for the amazing answer . I had a question as an extension. For sake of convenience , I am adding my columns with data types in a DataTable. And am adding the dataTable to ultragrid. Anyway I can configure the CellChange event for the table ?

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan I think this should be possible with Infragistics. I don't typically use DataTables, but I would try using the designer to add a CellChange event to your grid. Then set a breakpoint in the handler and have a look at CellEventArgs, in particular e.Cell.Column and e.Cell.Column.Key. This might get you started.

Answer (score 2):

why not make sure your data layer returns Bool, Infragistics grid will automatically (auto generate) Check Box for it

Comment: I am having the same issue. Adding it to your data layer might be wrong because some fields are a UI concern only and you should always be cautious not to mix your UI and Data layer code too much.